# Correlation matrix with all positive correlations positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to prove the above statement but not able to find an elegant way.... any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: yes 2x2 can be shown as sum of squared expressions with positive coefficients

Comment: What if two variables are perfectly correlated?

Answer (score 2):

That statement is not true in general.

For example,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.9 & 0.2 \\
0.9 & 1 & 0.7 \\
0.2 & 0.7 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: A correlation matrix must be positive semidefinite. Your example is not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The statement is false. The most obvious example is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the random variables are perfectly correlated. For a less obvious example, take any $n\times k$ random matrix $X$ such that (a) $n\ge k$, (b) all row sums of $X$ are zero and (c) in each column, all entries have the same sign. Then the covariance matrix $XX^T$ has deficient rank but it almost always have all positive entries. And so does the correlation matrix. For a concrete example, consider
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0&-1& 0\\
1& 1& 0&-2\\
0& 2&-1&-1\\
1& 1&-2& 0\\
1& 1&-1&-1
\end{pmatrix},
\ XX^T=\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&1&3&2\\
1&6&4&2&4\\
1&4&6&4&4\\
3&2&4&6&4\\
2&4&4&4&4
\end{pmatrix}.
$$